# Finding if Multiple Keys Map to the Same Value

Tags: java, collections, iterator, maps

In this problem, I have to have a map with keys and values of strings to see if multiple keys map to the same value. In other words, my method should return true of no two keys map to the same value while false if it does. My attempt to approach this was to put all the maps into a collection and examine each elem to see if there are two copies of the same value; that doesn't seem to be working for me however. Any suggestions will be appreciated, thanks.

The prompt:

Write a method isUnique that accepts a Map from strings to strings as a parameter and returns true if no two keys map to the same value (and false if any two or more keys do map to the same value). For example, calling your method on the following map would return true:

{Marty=Stepp, Stuart=Reges, Jessica=Miller, Amanda=Camp, Hal=Perkins}

Calling it on the following map would return false, because of two mappings for Perkins and Reges:

{Kendrick=Perkins, Stuart=Reges, Jessica=Miller, Bruce=Reges, Hal=Perkins}

The empty map is considered to be unique, so your method should return true if passed an empty map.

My attempt:

```
public static boolean isUnique(Map<String, String> input) {
    Collection<String> values = input.values(); // stores all the values into a collection

    for (String names: values) { // goes through each string to see if any duplicates
        Iterator<String> wordList = values.iterator(); // iterates words in values collection
        int repeat = 0; // counts number of repeats
        // goes through each elem to compare to names
        if (wordList.hasNext()) {
            if (wordList.next().equals(names)) {
                repeat++;
            }
        }
        if (repeat > 1) { // if more than one copy of the value exists = multiple keys to same value
            return false; // If multiple copies of same value exists
        }
    }
    return true; // all unique values
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, then I would implement your method generically like so -

```
public static <K, V> boolean isUnique(Map<K, V> input) {
  if (input == null || input.isEmpty()) {
    return true;
  }
  Set<V> set = new HashSet<V>();
  for (V value : input.values()) {
    set.add(value);
  }
  return set.size() == input.size();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't we be putting the values into the HashSet instead of the keys because we are trying to find duplicate maps so the HashSet can get rid of?

Comment: @JackL. I am putting duplicate values into the `Set`. `input.get(key)` returns a `V` value.

Comment: I see it now; my bad.

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be during iterating through the Map, you can store the values in Set of Strings. So if the size of original Map and Set is same, then there is no value that maps to two or more Key of Map.

As far as implementation goes, it can be done as follows:

```
public boolean checkMap(Map<String, String> map) {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

    for(Entry<String, String> entry:map.entrySet()) {
        set.add(entry.getValue);
    }

    if(map.size == set.size)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way that I can think of to do this is

```
public static boolean valuesAreUnique(Map<K,V> input) { 
    Collection<V> values = input.values();
    return (new HashSet<V>(values)).size() == values.size();
}
```

However, it's not the most performant way of doing this, because as it builds the set, it will keep adding elements even after a duplicate has been found.  So it would most likely perform better if you do the following, which takes advantage of the return value from the `add` method of the `Set` interface.

```
public static boolean valuesAreUnique(Map<K,V> input) { 
    Set<V> target = new HashSet<V>();
    for (V value: input.values()) {
        boolean added = target.add(value);
        if (! added) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: That's a cool way of doing it. I didn't know the add method had a return value. Since the list interface has pretty much identical sets of common methods, does it also return a value for lists too?

Comment: Well, yes, the `add` method does have a return value for `List`s, but it's not very useful, because it's always `true`, because a `List` is allowed to contain duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Shrikant Kakani's and Elliott Frisch's approach are correct. But, we can make it more efficient by stopping the iteration once we have found a duplicate:

```
public static boolean isUnique(Map<String, String> input) {
  Set<String> uniqueValues = new HashSet<String>();
  for (String value : input.values()) {
    if (uniqueValues.contains(value)) {
      return false;
    }
    uniqueValues.add(value);
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: You can make this even more efficient by using the return value from `add` - which basically makes it the same as the second part of my answer.

Comment: @DavidWallace Correct, David. Thanks. Your answer was not there when I wrote mine.

Answer (score 0):

The exercises from the book are specific to the chapter, and as far as I understand, it is expected to have a solution per the topic covered. Its understandable that there are multiple and better solutions, which have been submitted above, but the given exercise covers the Map, keys, values, and methods related to them. Using below method stops as soon as the Value is used the second time.

```
    public static boolean isUnique(Map<String, String> map){
        Map<String, Integer> check = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (String v : map.values()){
            if (check.containsKey(v)){
                return false;
            } else {
               check.put(v, 1);
            }
        }
        return true;        
    }
```